# EdDSA in bouncy castle

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I have code that makes use of the java bouncy castle libraries for encryption, decryption and signature verification.

Now I came across the situation where a third party has shared their public key that is of type EdDSA. And the files they send us are signed with corresponding private key.

In the bc source code we have:

`public static final int EDDSA = 22;            // EdDSA - (internet draft, but appearing in use)`

And the bc help method `PGPPublicKey.isEncryptionKey()` returns false for EdDSA

Does this somehow mean that BC doesn't fully support EdDSA?

Or is it just meant to **no**t be used for encryption, only signature verification? In that case, I guess I need to ask them either to change to an RSA key, or have them send me a separate public key for us to use if we want to send them encrypted files.

Comment: EdDSA is a signature algorithm, not an encryption algorithm. Since they are sending you *signed* files, you would use their public key to verify the signature.

Comment: **Yes EdDSA is sign-only.** [The OpenPGP draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-openpgp-crypto-refresh#section-9.2) supports 'Curve25519' (really X25519, it has been renamed) and X448 per RFC7748 for encryption, and just as a DSA sign-only masterkey usually has an EG encryption subkey, an EdDSA sign-only masterkey usually has a Bernstein-curve ECDH (really XDH) encryption subkey.